# WCF DataService indent xml response

Tags: xml, wcf, odata, indentation, dataservice

How can i indent the xml response from my data service?

All my request to the wcf data service are in xml wihout indent.

I am using `OData3 WCF Data Service 5.0`.

Before in Odata WCF Dataservice 4, all my response data was in indent xml.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that since wcf dataservice 4.0 was update in WCF Data Services 5.0 with OData 3.0, all the xml response is not intent, i solved this by implement the IDispatchMessageInspector interface and modify the current content by xdocument and xmlTextwriter .